# Accessing most frequent sub-value from a multi value dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am writing a script that finds all text files in a directory, then finds the number of lines in the files and the most frequent word. I am aware this is not the easiest/neatest way to do it but I'm quite new to python (2 weeks).

The small problem that I have encountered is that I have 2 main dictionaries. One stores the file and line count and the other one stores file, line count and word count with its frequency like so:

```
dict1_example = {'file':'lines'}
dict2_example = {'file': 'lines', ('word':'count')}
```

I would like to be able to extract the most frequent word from all files, i.e. access the ('word':'count') bit of the second dictionary.

Is there a way to get information just from that part or do I need to play around with the functions and create an additional dictionary just with `{'word':'count'}` ??

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import glob
import os
from sys import argv
import re
from collections import Counter

script, directory = argv

def file_len2(filename2):
    with open(filename2) as f2:
        l2 = [x for x in f2.readlines() if x != "\n"]
    return len(l2)

def word_count(filename3):
    with open(filename3) as f3:
        passage = f3.read()

    stop_words = ("THE", "OF", "A", "TO", "AND", "IS", "IN", "YOU", "THAT", "IT", "THIS", "YOUR", "AS", "AN", "BUT", "FOR")
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', passage)
    cap_words = [word.upper() for word in words if word.upper() not in stop_words]
    word_counts = Counter(cap_words)
    return max(word_counts, key=word_counts.get), word_counts[max(word_counts, key=word_counts.get)]



files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.txt")


length = {}
file_info = {}

for file in files:
    lines = file_len2(file)
    length[file] = lines
    file_info[file] = lines, word_count(file)


for file, lines in length.iteritems():
    print '{}: {}'.format(os.path.basename(file), lines), word_count(file);




maximum_file = max(length, key=length.get)
minimum_file = min(length, key=length.get)

maximum_lines = os.path.basename(max(length, key=length.get))
minimum_lines = os.path.basename(min(length, key=length.get))


print "The file with the maximum number of lines:" 
print "%r lines in %r " % (length[maximum_file], maximum_lines)

print "The file with the minimum number of lines:" 
print "%r lines in %r" % (length[minimum_file], minimum_lines)

sum_lines = sum(length.values())
number_of_values = len(length)

average = sum_lines / number_of_values

print "The average number of lines in a text file in given directory: ", average, "- Rounded down"
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved my problem by making another dictonary:

```
word_freq[file] = word_count(file)
```

and by switching around the return values on

```
def word_count(filename3)
```

then I used this to get the most common word:

```
print word_freq[max(word_freq, key=word_freq.get)]
```